# raise_application_error exception handling in subprocedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

I have multiple stored procedures calling multiple stored procedures in my database. To give a small example, I've constructed a fictionalised version of a few of them below. In my example, a Java program calls `calculate_bill`, which calls `calculate_commission`, which calls `update_record`.

I'm hoping to get some advice on how best to propagate the error messages up the stack to the calling Java layer, so the user gets a precise error message corresponding to wherever the error has occurred.

I'm really quite stuck on this. I've played around in my example with `raise_application_error` and just continually shuffling it up the stack. Is the way I'm doing it below remotely correct? Or is one raise_application_error in the relevant procedure enough, with no `pragma exception init` etc needed?

To give an idea of what I mean, in the example below, if a user entered a number which corresponded to a record which couldn't be updated because it didn't exist, I'd like them to get the message:
"Error calculating bill. Error calculating commission. No record exists to be updated" or something to that effect.

So two questions:

1. What is the best practice, most efficient, most tidy way to pass error messages up the stack for the end user in the application layer?
2. Does anyone have any suggestions on tidier output from the code, i.e. the best way to concatenate these errors to make them more meaningful? I'm really open to any suggestions on how to make this work best as I have absolutely no prior experience in this.

Example:
(Error in code):

```
-20000 : Error in top level procedure
-20001 : Error in middle level procedure
-20002 : Error in bottom level procedure
```

**Java code:**

```
try {
    // call calculate_bill
exception (SQLException ex)
    // output oracle code and relevant message.
```

**Oracle code:**

```
create or replace procedure calculate_bill(in_num NUMBER) 
is
error_calculating_commission EXCEPTION;
error_updating_record EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (error_calculating_commission, -20001);
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (error_updating_record , -20002);
begin
    if in_num > 2 then
        calculate_commission(in_num);
else
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error calculating bill. ' || 'Record number doesn''t exist.', false);
end if;
exception
    when error_calculating_commission then
        raise_application_error(SQLCODE, 'Error calculating bill. ' || SQLERRM, false);
    when error_updating_record then
        raise_application_error(SQLCODE, 'Error calculating bill. ' || SQLERRM, false);
    when others then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unknown error encountered calculating bill.', false);
end;

create or replace procedure calculate_commission(in_num NUMBER) 
is
begin
    if in_num < 30 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Number too small to calculate commission.', false);
    elsif in_num >= 30 and < 40 then
        declare
            error_storing_record EXCEPTION;
            PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (error_storing_record , -20002);
        begin
            update_record(in_num);
        exception
        when error_storing_record then
             raise_application_error(SQLCODE, 'Error calculating commission. ' || SQLERRM, false);
        when others then
             raise_application_error(-20001, 'Unknown error encountered calculating commission.', false);
    else
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Number too large to calculate commission', false);
    end if;
end;

create or replace procedure update_record(in_num NUMBER) 
is
begin
  //some SQL query with a where clause, where in_num equals something
exception
when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'No record exists to be updated', false);
when others then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'Unknown error encountered updating record.', false);
end if;
end;
```

Note: I know this example is a little contrived. I was just trying to keep it brief.

Comment: One way to do that is to pass the error code and description through the stored procedure interfaces themselves as output parameters. Doing it that way should give you more control and you'd be less constrained by Oracle's error handling percolation abilities. I don't work on Oracle so I won't speak to other designs it may cleanly support. Hopefully an Oracle expert chimes in.

Comment: I hope so, because your suggestions is bringing me full circle! When I started, that's exactly what I was doing and I was warned off it, as it was considered bad practice to pass errors as parameters. This is my "alternative" method, which I'm looking for tidy-up help with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would implement this is to use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` where the error actually originates, then leave it unhandled in the other layers (or, if you want to do logging in the database, catch it in the `OTHERS` section, then re-raise using `RAISE` rather than `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.

You're `OTHERS` sections are still perpetuating the problem raised in your previous question: when an unknown error occurs you're replacing it with a generic, unhelpful message. To paraphrase [Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jul/o47asktom-092692.html), "a `WHEN OTHERS` that does not end in `RAISE` is a bug`.

With no logging in the database, I would re-write the provided code like this:

```
create or replace procedure calculate_bill(in_num NUMBER) 
is
begin
    if in_num > 2 then
        calculate_commission(in_num);
else
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error calculating bill. ' || 'Record number doesn''t exist.', false);
end if;
end;

create or replace procedure calculate_commission(in_num NUMBER) 
is
begin
    if in_num < 30 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Number too small to calculate commission.', false);
    elsif in_num >= 30 and in_num < 40 then
        update_record(in_num);
    else
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Number too large to calculate commission', false);
    end if;
end;

create or replace procedure update_record(in_num NUMBER) 
is
v_stub number;
begin
  select 1 into v_stub from dual where 1 = 0;
exception
when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'No record exists to be updated', false);
end;
```

Below is sample input and the stack traces they created:

```
exec calculate_bill(0)
ORA-20000: Error calculating bill. Record number doesn't exist.
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_BILL", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1

exec calculate_bill(10)
ORA-20001: Number too small to calculate commission.
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_COMMISSION", line 5
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_BILL", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1

exec calculate_bill(35)
ORA-20002: No record exists to be updated
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.UPDATE_RECORD", line 8
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_COMMISSION", line 7
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_BILL", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1

exec calculate_bill(100)
ORA-20001: Number too large to calculate commission
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_COMMISSION", line 9
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMANAME.CALCULATE_BILL", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If you were to add error logging to these procedures, it would be a simple matter of adding an `OTHERS` clause to the `EXCEPTION` sections:

```
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      my_logging (SQLCODE, SQLERRM, DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace ());
      RAISE;
```

The new exception created by your `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` calls will be handled transparently by the `RAISE`.

Comment: This looks awesome. One final question. Let's say there is an issue finding a stored procedure, or a table. That would usually be handled in a "when others" block. In your example, would you simply log that, raise it and let the calling Java application determine how to deal with the wide range of possible errors that could occur and be trapped in a when others?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "an issue finding a stored procedure" . If a referenced procedure doesn't exist (or you don't have permission to access), anything that references it won't compile, so trying to handle it in the exception block would be pointless.